# Emulating Position Fixed with an Absolute Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

Trying to emulate position fixed (because I need the effect of `background-attachment: fixed`, on a div) and I can't seem to get it to perform well enough to use.

I've tried numerous variations, with transforms instead of top, with easings to ease the judder, and using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of scroll but they all suffer the same problem.

If you checkout the below fiddle you'll see how it works but it's very jumpy/laggy. Is it possible to fix this somehow?

```js
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('shape')[0];
var poffset = el.parentNode.offsetTop;
var scroll;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
 scroll = window.pageYOffset;
  poffset = el.parentNode.offsetTop;
 raf();
});

function raf(){
 
  el.style.transform = 'translateY('+parseInt(scroll-poffset)+'px)';
 
 // requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}
raf();
```

```css
.content {
 height: 100vh;
 background-color: #ace;
}

.fixed {
 height: 100vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.shape {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 margin-top: -150px;
 margin-left: -150px;
 background-color: #bada55;
 border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>

</div>
<div class="fixed">
 <i class="shape"></i>
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Transform `translateY` not `top`, throttle the scroll function call, and stop using `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: As I mentioned (and have commented out) I've tried translateY but the result is the same.

Comment: _"tried translateY but the result is the same"_ - this isn't true. The performance difference is significant in some browsers. In your case it's likely to be a combination of issues, rather than one, which causes the "lag".

Comment: it is neither jumpy or laggy here, but i can see the element moving a little bit (seems it needs time to "catch" his position back, like i was animated)

Comment: The performance of transforms may be better, but something is causing it to jump. See codepen: https://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/rmOzoX for a version implements what you suggested. (throttle, transforms).

Comment: The commented out `translateY` has no lag or jump, but you will need to figure out the correct math to put it in the right place.

Comment: Seems to work jump-free on the expanded fiddle here, but jumps a lot on Codepen's Debug view... Fixed the positioning Math now too. Will have to see how it looks on the correct environment.